# Unable to authenticate Microsoft personal account using OAuth2

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, exchangewebservices

I have an application that uses OAuth2 to authenticate to M365 standard users, works fine. Now we have a user with an outlook.com address that does not work. Based on some documentation I found, I changed the login url to:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=...
```

(for standard users, I have "common" instead of "consumers".

I also needed to change two properties in the manifest of my application in Azure AD:

```
"accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
"signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
```

With these changes, I get to the Microsoft login screen, followed by the request for permissions. Once I accept, I get the error message "Sorry, but we're having trouble signing you in", followed by "AADSTS90023 Microsoft account logins are not supported".

Meanwhile, I get an email from Microsoft saying "New App(s) have access to your data". Any idea how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I created an **Azure AD Multitenant** Application:

[image]

> **Note** that: You can make use of **`common`** endpoint to authenticate both Multitenant and Microsoft personal account users as the  `signInAudience` is  `AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount`. Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist#solution-use-the-correct-sign-in-url).

I used the below endpoint to **authenticate Multitenant and Microsoft personal accounts users**"

*Even using `consumers` endpoint, the Microsoft Personal users must be able to authenticate.*

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

[image]

And I got the email:

[image]

***If still the issue persists,*** Check the below:

- The error "***AADSTS90023 Microsoft account logins are not supported***" usually occurs if the Azure AD Application is not configured to support sign of personal accounts.
- Try singing in with other Microsoft personal account user and check.
- Try signing in Incognito window and check.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried switching back to "common" and leaving my manifest changes in place, but it did not seem to help.  Part of my problem I think is that Microsoft is not allowing me to enter credentials, it just assumes I'm logged in to some other account, even though I am not.  In my login URL, I'm specifying "prompt=consent" which I thought forced a new login.  I can't find any documentation about that option now - does it still work, or is there something else?

Comment: Can you try in Incognito window or clear the browser cache

Comment: Try prompt=login

Comment: Clearing the cache does allow me to login to the correct account.  But I'm having trouble getting the token. Http error 400, error AADSTS70011, "One or more scopes in 'offline_access EWS.AccessAsUser.All User.Read Files.ReadWrite.All' are not compatible with each other".  Again, this code works fine if I am logging into a M365 work/school account.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you passing the same scopes for the work account login request?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, this is the same exact code, except I am using "consumers" instead of "common" in the various URLs.  I changed the manifest of the application to allow "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",

Comment: Can you try to authenticate the personal Microsoft user by **not** passing EWS.AccessAsUser.All scope?